# If within map function: Getting unexpected error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, if-statement

I get an unexpected error while following some code examples which I found online. I assume I have made some mistake, but comparing to other examples here, I cannot find the mistake. I am trying to include an if function within a map function:

```
const compProfileRemoveHandler = compProfileId => {
    todoList.map(profile =>(
     if (profile.id !== compProfileId) {some code}
))};
```

Does anyone know why I get the following error: "Parsing error: Unexpected token" (and the 'if' is marked under the statement).

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: you need to use curly braces instead of round brackets for your function body `.map(profile => { if ..})` - also you must always return something from your `map` method or you'll get `undefined` as your element

Comment: @NickParsons also remember that if you're returning an object, it's the implicit return feature, but you need to wrap the object in parentheses to avoid it being parsed as the body.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
const compProfileRemoveHandler = compProfileId => {
    todoList.map(profile => {
     if (profile.id !== compProfileId) {some code}
} )};
```